# on.('save') event using x-editable

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I'm using following code to detect when values are saved.

```
$('.qty').on('save', function() { // .qty can be also .id or .price etc
    ...
}
```

Do I need to set this for every field or can I just use some global event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.qty')` will match all elements with the qty class. So what you have will add your event listener to all of those matched elements.